# Skip_over() algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator

I'm just curious if this is clear to the average person.

```
template<typename IteratorType>
inline IteratorType skip_over(
    IteratorType begin,
    IteratorType end,
    typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorType>::value_type skippedCharacter)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorType>::value_type value_type;
    return std::find_if(begin, end, 
            std::not1(
                 std::bind2nd(std::equal_to<value_type>(), skippedCharacter)
            )
        );
}
```

Comment: It took me a while to work out what it did (comments would not go amiss).

Answer (score 7):

A few comments:

- Algorithms typically use the names `first` and `last` for the iterators they take, not `begin` and `end` (in common usage, `begin` and `end` refer specifically to the iterators that delimit a range in a container).
- The use of `find_if` seems a bit excessive:  yes, it is good to use the Standard Library algorithms, but if you are writing your own algorithm, you may as well just write a loop, especially if it makes the code much clearer.
- With respect to template parameter naming, it is helpful if you say what category of iterator is required; this helps to document the algorithm.

Consider the following, alternative implementation:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator, typename T>
ForwardIterator skip_over(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, T const& x)
{
    while (first != last && *first == x)
        ++first;

    return first;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I think I'd prefer `for (;first!=last && *first==x; ++first); return first;` (with the empty semicolon on its own line, of course).